# Imaginary Lorentz factor in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, faster-than-light, complex-numbers, tachyon

[image]

This thing is making me confuse, what is mean by imaginary Lorentz factor in Physics? What is the physical meaning of imaginary?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67134/

Comment: Thanks I just found the answer in the Related questions.

Comment: The mistake is at the line "Now if $u>c$".

Answer (score 0):

[It just means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number) a complex number of zero real part, so its square is negative.